# How does Python Scikit Learn handle linear separation problem in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, python, regularization, separation

There are already posts about warnings from R dealing with logistic regression and linear separation such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression). I just wanna make sure if in Python Scikit Learn this problem is all solved by the L1/L2 regularization part in the optimization function. In other words, it's safe to say users will not get any infinite MLE estimates warnings from `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` uses penalized logistic regression which "solves" the problem of perfect separation. If you set `C` to something too large, you might still end up with bad results, though.

Comment: Why we need to bother with regularization when data are linearly separable? I mean the weights can go to infinity but the decision boundary won't change.

Comment: @adosar Two things here: computational and statistical. Computationally (what this question was about), it's annoying to have your weights go to infinity; small regularization prevents that. Statistically, remember that if the dimension is greater than the number of data points, then _almost any_ dataset (in the measure theoretic sense) linearly separable; this is an example where you might expect regularization to be important for finding the "right" decision boundary to generalize well. (If the dimension is high but less than $n$, it can still be very helpful, depending.)